# A/B testing - how to in Craft?

Tags: templating, conditional, content

What's your process for A/B testing a Craft entry? I'm curious about how you'd structure alternative content for a page within Craft and what tools you'd use to measure the results.

Any comments appreciated - I know there are lots of different ways you could approach this!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set a cookie from your template, which assigns visitors to specific groups:

---

**Craft 2:** *(Use the [LJ Cookies](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-cookies) plugin)*

```twig
{% set testGroup = craft.lj_cookies.get('group') %}

{% if not testGroup %}
    {# New user - assign them to a group at random #}
    {% set testGroup = random(['a', 'b']) %}
    {% set expires = now|date_modify('+30 days').timestamp %}
    {% do craft.lj_cookies.set('group', testGroup, expires) %}
{% endif %}
```

**Craft 3:**

```twig
{% set testGroup = craft.app.request.cookies.get('group') %}

{% if not testGroup %}
    {# New user - assign them to a group at random #}
    {% set testGroup = random(['a', 'b']) %}
    {% set expires = now|date_modify('+30 days').timestamp %}
    {% do craft.app.response.cookies.add(create({
         class: 'yii\\web\\Cookie',
         name: 'group',
         value: testGroup,
         httpOnly: true
    })) %} 
{% endif %}
```

---

And then reference that `testGroup` variable whenever you need to know which group they’re in:

```twig
{% switch testGroup %}
    {% case 'a' %}
        ....
    {% case 'b' %}
        ....
{% endswitch %}
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you can actually have multiple sets of test groups at the same time, using different cookie/variable names. You’re also not limited to two groups per set.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Brandon.

Comment: Thanks, is this still the best approach for AB testing 3 years later?

Comment: @mateostabio I would saying cookies is still a viable option. Without any account based system in place it's really a easy and low maintenance way of doing A/B testing

Answer (score 1):

https://plugins.craftcms.com/optimum?craft4

https://github.com/matfish2/craft-optimum

The Optimum plugin allows for server-side A/B/n testing in Craft.
You can set multiple experiments on the same page, each with unlimited variants. The plugin automatically sends the data to a GA4 custom dimension.

Full disclosure: I'm the author.